# How to present tree of id / hierarchical query

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I'm fighting with hierarchical query but finally I have to give up.

I need to present all tree/hierarchy ID on input belongs to.

Maybe the best way will be to show what I want to do on examples:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS (ID NUMBER)
;
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS (ID NUMBER,ORDER_ID NUMBER, PARENT_ID NUMBER)
;
CREATE TABLE WANT_TO_PRESENT (ID NUMBER);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (65733);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (23423);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (456765);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (23464);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (77532);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES (1,65733,3);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES (2,23423,3);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES (3,77532,4);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES (4,23464,0); 
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES (5,456765,null);
```

**Example 1:**

```
INSERT INTO WANT_TO_PRESENT(ID) VALUES (23464)
```

then output should be only 23464 because of `parent_id = 0` or `null`

**Example 2:**

```
INSERT INTO WANT_TO_PRESENT(ID) VALUES (23423)
```

then output should be: 65733,23423,77532,23464

Why 65733 - because of parent_id the same like 23423 has.

**Example 3:**

```
INSERT INTO WANT_TO_PRESENT(ID) VALUES (23464,65733)
```

then output should be: the output should be:

65733,23423,77532,23464, 65733 - same like above

I was wondering If I really need table orders to present the tree though all data I find in Products table.

Could you give me some tips? Some explanation, I would like to finally understand how hierarchical query works...

edit:

```
insert into products values (6,23422,7);
insert into products values (7,56435,0);
truncate table WANT_TO_PRESENT;
INSERT INTO WANT_TO_PRESENT(ID) VALUES (56435);
```

Comment: You state in the comment to an answer that if the input is `56435` then the output should include its child: `56435,23422`; why, when the expected answer for example 1 is `23464` and does not include its children (`77532,65733,24322`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/97fd66/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS (ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (65733);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (23423);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (456765);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (23464);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (77532);
insert into ORDERS values (23422);
insert into ORDERS values (56435);

CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS (
  ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  ORDER_ID NUMBER REFERENCES ORDERS(ID),
  PARENT_ID NUMBER
);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES (1,65733,3);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES (2,23423,3);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES (3,77532,4);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES (4,23464,0); 
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES (5,456765,null);
insert into products values (6,23422,7);
insert into products values (7,56435,0);
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH WantToPresent( ID ) AS (
  SELECT 23464 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT ORDER_ID
FROM   PRODUCTS p
START WITH
  EXISTS( SELECT 'X'
          FROM   WantToPresent w
          WHERE  p.ORDER_ID = w.ID )
CONNECT BY ID = PRIOR parent_id
UNION
SELECT ORDER_ID
FROM   PRODUCTS p
START WITH
  EXISTS( SELECT 'X'
          FROM   WantToPresent w
          WHERE  p.ORDER_ID = w.ID )
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = parent_id
UNION
SELECT p2.ORDER_ID
FROM   PRODUCTS p1
       INNER JOIN
       PRODUCTS p2
       ON ( p1.PARENT_ID = p2.PARENT_ID AND p2.PARENT_ID <> 0 )
       INNER JOIN
       WantToPresent w
       ON ( p1.ORDER_ID = w.ID )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/97fd66/3/0)**:

```
| ORDER_ID |
|----------|
|    23423 |
|    23464 |
|    65733 |
|    77532 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
WITH WantToPresent( ID ) AS (
  SELECT 23423 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT ORDER_ID
FROM   PRODUCTS p
START WITH
  EXISTS( SELECT 'X'
          FROM   WantToPresent w
          WHERE  p.ORDER_ID = w.ID )
CONNECT BY 
  ID = PRIOR parent_id
UNION
SELECT ORDER_ID
FROM   PRODUCTS p
START WITH
  EXISTS( SELECT 'X'
          FROM   WantToPresent w
          WHERE  p.ORDER_ID = w.ID )
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = parent_id
UNION
SELECT p2.ORDER_ID
FROM   PRODUCTS p1
       INNER JOIN
       PRODUCTS p2
       ON ( p1.PARENT_ID = p2.PARENT_ID AND p2.PARENT_ID <> 0 )
       INNER JOIN
       WantToPresent w
       ON ( p1.ORDER_ID = w.ID )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/97fd66/3/1)**:

```
| ORDER_ID |
|----------|
|    23423 |
|    23464 |
|    65733 |
|    77532 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
WITH WantToPresent( ID ) AS (
  SELECT 23464 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 65733 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT ORDER_ID
FROM   PRODUCTS p
START WITH
  EXISTS( SELECT 'X'
          FROM   WantToPresent w
          WHERE  p.ORDER_ID = w.ID )
CONNECT BY 
  ID = PRIOR parent_id
UNION
SELECT ORDER_ID
FROM   PRODUCTS p
START WITH
  EXISTS( SELECT 'X'
          FROM   WantToPresent w
          WHERE  p.ORDER_ID = w.ID )
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = parent_id
UNION
SELECT p2.ORDER_ID
FROM   PRODUCTS p1
       INNER JOIN
       PRODUCTS p2
       ON ( p1.PARENT_ID = p2.PARENT_ID AND p2.PARENT_ID <> 0 )
       INNER JOIN
       WantToPresent w
       ON ( p1.ORDER_ID = w.ID )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/97fd66/3/2)**:

```
| ORDER_ID |
|----------|
|    23423 |
|    23464 |
|    65733 |
|    77532 |
```

**Query 4**:

```
WITH WantToPresent( ID ) AS (
  SELECT 56435 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT ORDER_ID
FROM   PRODUCTS p
START WITH
  EXISTS( SELECT 'X'
          FROM   WantToPresent w
          WHERE  p.ORDER_ID = w.ID )
CONNECT BY 
  ID = PRIOR parent_id
UNION
SELECT ORDER_ID
FROM   PRODUCTS p
START WITH
  EXISTS( SELECT 'X'
          FROM   WantToPresent w
          WHERE  p.ORDER_ID = w.ID )
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = parent_id
UNION
SELECT p2.ORDER_ID
FROM   PRODUCTS p1
       INNER JOIN
       PRODUCTS p2
       ON ( p1.PARENT_ID = p2.PARENT_ID AND p2.PARENT_ID <> 0 )
       INNER JOIN
       WantToPresent w
       ON ( p1.ORDER_ID = w.ID )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/97fd66/3/3)**:

```
| ORDER_ID |
|----------|
|    23422 |
|    56435 |
```

Comment: Hello, MTO thanks. But take a look, first query, Want to delete contain : 23464 , so 23464 is the parent of 65733,23423,77532. Look: (1,65733,3) so ID 1 is child of ID number 3, next (2,23423,3) , 2 is child of number 3, (3,77532,4) - 3 is child of number 4, (4,23464,0) - over , 4 is a parent. Sometimes instead of 0 is null. So result in query1 should be: 65733,23423,77532,23464

Comment: That is not what you wrote in the question as to your expected output.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was lookin for... I need to analyze that because I would to finally understand hierarchy query : ) Thanks again!

Comment: The first hierarchical query gets all the parents, the second hierarchical query gets all the children and the final (non-hierarchical) query of the union gets all the ids that share the same parent.

Answer (score 1):

You must combine two queries:

First climb up to the root of the parents ID's in the `PRODUCT` table. Then from this root go down to all childern.

One thing make it more difficult. The product 4 has root parent 0, but there is no records with this key. Product 5 is root and has parent NULL. This is handled in the `START WITH` clause which could be simplified if you would use unique notation.

```
with to_root as (
select 
  t1.id,
  connect_by_root(t1.PARENT_ID) as root
from 
  products t1
where t1.id in (select id from PRODUCTS 
                 where ORDER_ID in (select id from WANT_TO_PRESENT))
start with nvl(t1.PARENT_ID,0) = 0
connect by t1.PARENT_ID = prior t1.id
),
go_down as (
select 
  t1.id,
  t1.parent_id
from 
  products t1
start with  PARENT_ID  in (select  root  from to_root) or  
                   ID in (select  ID  from to_root)
connect by   t1.PARENT_ID =  prior t1.id
)
--select * from to_root;
select ORDER_ID from PRODUCTS
where id in (
select id from go_down
)
order by 1
;
```

gives for you test data:

```
truncate table WANT_TO_PRESENT;
INSERT INTO WANT_TO_PRESENT(ID) VALUES (23464);

23423
23464
65733
77532

truncate table WANT_TO_PRESENT;
INSERT INTO WANT_TO_PRESENT(ID) VALUES (456765);

456765

truncate table WANT_TO_PRESENT;
INSERT INTO WANT_TO_PRESENT(ID) VALUES (23464);
INSERT INTO WANT_TO_PRESENT(ID) VALUES (65733);

23423
23464
65733
77532
```

Comment: Marmite, thanks for reply : ) unfortanely it doesn't work as I thought. Take a look please at my edit, I inserted into products 2 other values, and into want_to_present value :56435. Not the output should b e only 23422 and 56435.   56345 - as parent. 23422 - as child